# Unable to access certain websites

Tags: asp.net, web, asp

I am unable to access certain websites from my PC viz. google.com, gmail.com , stackoverflow.com, etc. However, I am able to access facebook.com, twitter.com, infoq.com etc. Currently I am accessing Google via proxy server. I suspect that the problem might exist with websites that have used ASP for scripting. Please suggest a solution to the problem that I am facing.

Comment: Use PHP instead? :P

Comment: It is highly unlikely that this has anything to do with the server-side scripting language. In many cases, your browser cannot even see what language is being used (if any). This question is therefore a better fit for Super User.

Comment: @Thomas : I understand what you said, but I am unable to access any website based on asp or asp.net. However, foursquare.com scripted in Scala, twitter.com scripted on RoR & Scala, facebook.com scripted in PHP are all accessible.

Comment: Could be a DNS issue if not access-restriction. try setting your DNS to 4.2.2.2 or 4.2.2.3

Comment: Which browser are you using and which operating system? When you say you can't access is there a specific error message?

Comment: Google does not use ASP.

Comment: i am bot able to access facebook nd hotmail account.....either the loading never ends or sometimes they open in a semi html form....whereas i can access anyother site......google is working properly......what is the problem??......pls suggest....

Comment: have you checked your hosts file i had the same problem the other day where it had added some texst there that dosnt allow you to go to google or other seach engines. all i did was delete the lines of text at the bottem of the docuemnt and saved over the top of orginal and it worked

Answer (score 2):

When you say "does not load", what happens? Does the page show up blank, or is there a browser error? If there is a browser error, what does it say? Does the page start to load but never finish?

Answer (score 1):

could be your hosts file, some virus's update it.

If not that, try with other web browsers (Firefox, Opera, Safari)

Answer (score 1):

The difference in language used to build the sites is a red herring. By the time your browser sees the data it's all HTML and JavaScript.

Have you got a JavaScript blocker running?

If so has it been set to block all scripts or just scripts from some sites?

If it's just some sites, is it those sites on your list of inaccessible ones?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a DNS issue if not access-restriction. try setting your DNS to 4.2.2.2 or 4.2.2.3

Comment: Tried setting DNS to the ones you specified. Still the problem persists. :(